# Spark DataFrame instance a new column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, I groupByKey on my first Column to have a String Array and I would like instance a new object in new column of my dataframe.

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|name       |Thing                                                      |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|253        |[a, b, c, d, e]                                            |
|095        |[f, g]                                                     |
|282        |[h, i, j]                                                  |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

My object that I would instance have this structure :

```
public MyObject(String name,
               String[] Thing)
```

I define a caseclass to use DataFrame :

```
 case class Myclass(name: String, Thing: Array[String])
```

To achieve this goal I use an UDF function :

```
  def myFunction(name : String, Thing: Array[String]): MyObject= {
  return new MyObject(name , Thing)
}
```

My code like this :

```
var my_df = my_old_df.map(line=>(line(0).asInstanceOf[String],line(1).asInstanceOf[String]))
  .groupByKey()

val my_next_df : DataFrame= my_df.map(line => Myclass(line._1.toString,line._2.toArray)).toDF()

val myudf= sqlContext.udf.register("myudf", myFunction _)

val my_df_problem  = my_next_df.withColumn("Object", myudf($"name", $"Thing"))
```

I have instanciation problem : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Library.class is not supported

Comment: Shouldn't your UDF read `... : MyClass` not not `... : MyObject`? Anyway, you are done after the second line of code you have. You don't need lines 3 & 4 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems UDF must return `MyClass` type.

```
val myudf= sqlContext.udf
      .register("myudf", (name : String, thing: Array[String]) => new MyClass(name , thing))
```